# Joshua X1 Rear Sprocket

Tags: sprocket

I need a rear sprocket for a 1997 Joshua X1.  Are they available anywhere?  I live in North Carolina.  If not does anyone buy the MTB for parts?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has a freehub and 7 speed shifters by [default](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=68362). So you just need a 7 speed Shimano cassette ([note the difference between a cassette and freewheel](http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html)), which you can find at your local bike shop pretty easily or online.

The default is a Shimano-compatible (made by Shimano, SRAM, IRD, etc.) 7 speed 11-30t cassette. Your LBS probably has some laying around - according to [Sheldon Brown's site](http://sheldonbrown.com/k7-7.shtml), that exact cassette is no longer made, but there are several other close ones like [this](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/sram-pg730-7-speed-mtb-cassette/rp-prod6387).

You need some [tools for replacing a cassette](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal), so it might be cheaper (and it is like a 5 minute job) for your LBS to do it.